# Sharepoint workflow 2013 - content approval comment

Tags: workflow, content, approval, comments

I wonder if anybody had similar issue, I have a simple workflow to approve content (documents) but cant seem to figure out a workflow way to populate comments in version history (pic below).

[image: Versioning]

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the content approval comments will not populate the version comments (also called checkin comments)

So did this:

```
Check out item in Current Item

Check in item in Current Item with comment: Parameter: Comments

Set content approval status in Current Item to Approved . Comments: Parameter: Comments
```

Looks like that does the trick, still needs more testing though.